# Problems when writing a batch file to repeat a paragraph containing %PATH%

Tags: batch-file

I have written the following batch file that will write 100 paragraphs into a .bat file with incremental number changes to the file names referred.

```
for /l %%N in (1 5 500) do (
echo cd /D "C:\batch"
echo set PATH=C:\batch; &PATH%
echo echo Simulation 'g=0.00%%N.pre' started...
echo call %SOLVERQSP%-fp 1 -nt 3 ^
"C:\batch\0.00%%N.pre" > "C:\batch\g=0.00%%N.out"
echo echo Simulation 'g=0.00%%N' finished...
echo echo.
```

The problem is that the batch file is not created when the %PATH% and %SOLVERQSP% commands are present.  If i remove these the script runs fine.  Any suggestions of where I am going wrong or how I can avoid this

Comment: Is `&PATH%` just a typo here?

Comment: Also, have you tried the `echo call %SOLVERQSP%...` command on one line, i.e., without the `^` character?

Comment: I don't what `%SOLVERQSP%` does, but do you really need to change directories and set `PATH` for every iteration?

Comment: Are the echo's only for demonstration, or do you try to redirect the output to a new batch file?

Comment: So you are getting no error messages? Make sure you set `ECHO ON` to see any error messages. Missing quotes and syntax errors like `&PATH%` should be lit up, but maybe everything is just being interpreted as a string to echo. Still, you should post the output here even if there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the `%` by doubling them:

```
echo set PATH=C:\batch;%%PATH%%
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it will fail, as it will expand to nothing. `^%PATH^%` tries to expand `%PATH^%` which should be undefined.

Comment: @jeb It worked on the command line with the carets, within a batch file double-`%` are needed.

Comment: @marapt - Yes, but the code seems to be a batch-file. And even on the command line it's not very stable, as it will also look if a variable exists `path^` and only if is undefined, then it will output the `%path%`

Comment: @jeb That's why I tested and updated my answer. Great catch about `path^` at the command line!

Answer (score 0):

You should use some quotes and avoid the caret in your case

```
for /l %%N in (1 5 500) do (
  echo cd /D "C:\batch"
  echo set "PATH=C:\batch; %PATH%"
  echo echo Simulation 'g=0.00%%N.pre' started...
  echo call %%SOLVERQSP%%-fp 1 -nt 3 "C:\batch\0.00%%N.pre" > "C:\batch\g=0.00%%N.out"
  echo echo Simulation 'g=0.00%%N' finished...
  echo echo.
)
```